# Form submitting even with invalid fields MVC razor

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So in MVC I am trying to submit a form but even with certain fields required and if I hit my submit button twice it will still go through.

my razor syntax

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, Model.Options, new { id = "DropDown"  })
```

my view model

```
[Range(1,Int32.MaxValue)]
public Int32 ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
```

and the dropdown is populated using a dictionary in my controller so each list item has text and a value

and here is the generated html

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-range="The field ID must be between 1 and 2147483647." data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Company" name="ID">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
<option value="10">choice1</option>
<option value="11">choice2</option>
<option value="12">choice3</option>
<option value="13">choice4</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas why it will validate on the first click but on the second click the form submits with no data?

Comment: Yes its the ID that's required. I've tried it both with what I have and using Required rather than Range but with just using Required it will submit right away (Without picking an option) because it will count Select as a valid option because it has value="0". with the range it is basically saying its required and the value must be between 1 and whatever the max int value is.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally double clicked and deleted the user's comment. What it said was is it supposed to be the ID that's required and not the Options. Sorry to whoever that was if you see this

Comment: Do you have ClientValidationEnabled set to true in the web.config? Double check your versions of jQuery and jQuery Validate to ensure they are compatible, and be sure that they are included on the page.

Comment: Yes ClientValidationEnabled is set to true in the projects Web.config, In my specific areas folder's web.config it is not, but I'm assuming that since it is true for the generic Web.config it will be the same?

Comment: Also I'm assuming the versions of jQuery and jQuery Validate are compatible as they are working on other areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there was some jQuery function I wrote that basically if there was no option was selected it didn't submit it and that was causing this issue. Thanks to all that helped.